# How can you select the same UUID value twice per row in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

How can you select the same UUID value twice per row in MySQL?

Example code:

```
SELECT CONCAT('A: ', A, ', ', B, '-----', B) C
FROM
(
  SELECT UUID() B
    ,A
  FROM
  (
    SELECT 1 A
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2
  ) IQ
) OQ;
```

Expected values:

- C (column)
- A: 1, aaaaaaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaaaaaaaaaa-----aaaaaaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaaaaaaaaaa
- A: 2, bbbbbbbb-bbbb-bbbb-bbbb-bbbbbbbbbbbb-----bbbbbbbb-bbbb-bbbb-bbbb-bbbbbbbbbbbb

Actual example output from code sample above:

- C (column)
- A: 1, a1a3a027-e0fc-11e6-9aa2-bcee7b9e8497-----a1a3a038-e0fc-11e6-9aa2-bcee7b9e8497
- A: 2, a1a3a047-e0fc-11e6-9aa2-bcee7b9e8497-----a1a3a04a-e0fc-11e6-9aa2-bcee7b9e8497

In other words, I cannot get the digits in the 7 and 8 (one-based) indices to be the same for the same row.

I have also tried wrapping the UUID() function in MID, CONCAT, and CAST to no avail.

MySQL Version:

```
C:\[directory]\mysql\data>mysql -V
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.17, for Win32 (AMD64)
```

Comment: Aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa

Comment: Why the down vote? Whether there is some obvious problem with my example code or if there really is a bug in MySQL, an answer would be more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem by storing the result of UUID() inline as a variable, even if I never use the variable:

```
SELECT CONCAT('A: ', A, ', ', B, '-----', B) C
FROM
(
    SELECT
```

```
        @unused := #otherwise useless variable
```

```
            UUID() B
        ,A
    FROM
    (
        SELECT 1 A
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 2
    ) IQ
) OQ;
```